# Can I include another PDF in CFDOCUMENT?

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a PDF generated in Coldfusion. I would like to add pages from another PDF sitting in the folder.
I've checked cfpdf,  but it doesn't seem to be the way to go.
Is there a way to do this?

```
<cfdocument format="PDF" fontEmbed = "yes" pageType="A4" margintop="0.2" marginbottom="0.1" marginleft="0.2" marginright="0.2">
        <cfinclude template="header.inc">
        ... content ....
        pages 2nd PDF should be here
</cfdocument>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in its simplest form is how to append an existing PDF on disk to a dynamically created PDF and serve it to the browser without writing anything new to the physical or virtual file system.

```
<!--- Create a new PDF and store it in a variable called newPdf --->
<cfdocument format="PDF" name="newPdf">
  Content of new PDF here. Content of an existing PDF to be appended below.
</cfdocument>

<!--- Append to the new PDF the contents of the existing PDF located in the same folder as this script and store it in a variable called mergedPdf --->
<cfpdf action="merge" name="mergedPdf">
    <cfpdfparam source="newPdf">
    <cfpdfparam source="existing.pdf">
</cfpdf>

<!--- Output the merged PDF to the browser --->
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" variable="#ToBinary( mergedPdf )#" reset="true">
```

(You might want to add a `<cfheader>` to suggest how the PDF should be handled by the browser, ie `inline` or `attachment`.)

Comment: Tested with Adobe CF9.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [action="merge" attribute of cfpdf](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-798f.html).

Comment: I did, but in my current setup the PDF document is generated after clicking on a link and immediately served to the user, with CFPDF it is only saved to disk, right?

Comment: You can write to RAM... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-70e2363b121825b20e7-8000.html

Comment: You can of course, in the link request, still write your cfdocument pdf to disk, ideally using getTempDirectory(), and then use cfpdf action="merge" and then render the pdf directly to the browser using cfheader and cfcontent.